ImagePullBackOff or ErrImagePull error while deploying app to kubernetes
I try to deploy my application to Kubernetes environment. But I get ImagePullBackOff or ErrImagePull errors.
My app.yaml file for k8s configuration.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: node-docker
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      todo: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        todo: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: todo-site
        image: berkesayin/developing-with-containers:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: todo-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    todo: web
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort: 30001

The image I used here exists at my Dockerhub profile publicly:

https://hub.docker.com/r/berkesayin/developing-with-containers: berkesayin/developing-with-containers

I used different tags:

berkesayin/developing-with-containers:1.0
berkesayin/developing-with-containers
berkesayin/developing-with-containers:latest

None of them worked. Here are the steps I followed:
kubectl config get-contexts

# CURRENT   NAME             CLUSTER          AUTHINFO         NAMESPACE
# *         docker-desktop   docker-desktop   docker-desktop
#           minikube         minikube         minikube         default

kubectl apply -f app.yaml

# deployment.apps/node-docker created
# service/todo-entrypoint created                                                                                                                                                        

kubectl get pods

# NAME                          READY   STATUS            RESTARTS  NODE            NOMIN. NODE
# node-docker-cc84f4bb4-7mff2   0/1     ImagePullBackOff  0         docker-desktop  none

The image exists at my Dockerhub profile and I point to the correct image and tag. What causes the ImagePullBackOff problem here?

Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or DevOps. These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

I do able to replicate your issue and it seems that the image can be pulled.
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  2m29s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned sample/node-docker-796fd5795c-ctggm to multinode-demo-m03
  Normal  Pulling    2m29s  kubelet            Pulling image "berkesayin/developing-with-containers:latest"
  Normal  Pulled     2m24s  kubelet            Successfully pulled image "berkesayin/developing-with-containers:latest" in 4.275s (4.275s including waiting). Image size: 203390478 bytes.
  Normal  Created    2m23s  kubelet            Created container todo-site
  Normal  Started    2m23s  kubelet            Started container todo-site

Can you check if the host where your minkube is located does have internet access and try to create it with other namespace.

Thanks for the answer Ron Etch. I figured out that pushing the image only compatible with linux/amd64 platform causes the error, ImagePullBackOff when deploying the application to Kubernetes, because I use arm64 architecture. I updated the image making it both compatible with amd64 and arm64 platforms, which solves the problems. Thanks for pulling the image and suggestion.
